# How can I make the JMenuBar strape dissapear after the buttons?

Tags: java, swing, jmenubar

How can I make the JMenuBar streak dissapear after the menuitems? I want to put a 2nd menu in the middle of the frame, and it looks weird with this streak.

I tried to set the background to Panel.background but it doesn't work.

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class SwingMenuDemo extends JPanel {

   public SwingMenuDemo(){
        setLayout(null);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menuBar.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Panel.background"));
        menuBar.setBounds(0, 0, 450, 25);

        add(menuBar);

        JButton btn1 = new JButton("Menu1");
        menuBar.add(btn1);

        JButton btn2 = new JButton("Menu2");
        menuBar.add(btn2);

        JButton btn3 = new JButton("Menu3");
        menuBar.add(btn3);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGUI() {
       JFrame frame = new JFrame("SwingMenuDemo");

       frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(),BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
       frame.getContentPane().add(new SwingMenuDemo());
       frame.pack();
       frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               createAndShowGUI();
           }
       });
   }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any reason why you totally don't follow the [usual way of using JMenuBar elements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create your own "menu" of several JButtons, then don't use JMenu and don't use `null` layout and `setBounds(...)` (you should avoid the latter just as a general rule). Instead nest JPanels, each using its own layout manager to allow for simple creation of complex GUI's.

For instance you could create a JPanel to hold the buttons, say called menuPanel, give it a `new GridLayout(1, 0)` layout, meaning it will hold a grid of components in 1 row, and a variable number of columns (that's what the `0` means). Then put your buttons in that.

Then place that JPanel into another JPanel that uses say `FlowLayout.LEADING, 0, 0)` as its layout -- it will push all its components to the left.

Then make the main GUI use a BorderLayout and add the above panel to it's top in the `BorderLayout.PAGE_START` position. For example:

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SwingMenuDemo2 extends JPanel {
    private static final String[] MENU_TEXTS = {"Menu 1", "Menu 2", "Menu 3"};
    private static final int PREF_W = 400;
    private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;

    public SwingMenuDemo2() {
        JPanel menuPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        for (String menuText : MENU_TEXTS) {
            menuPanel.add(new JButton(menuText));
        }

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING, 0, 0));
        topPanel.add(menuPanel);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        SwingMenuDemo2 mainPanel = new SwingMenuDemo2();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Swing Menu Demo 2");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with

```
menuBar.setBorderPainted(false);
```